# Joomla language file reverse search

Tags: php, joomla

I have a component with its language file. A field in one of our tables contains a string from the language file and in the client the string is substituted with the corresponding value but the user can query on it. Obviously, the user will query using the string he reads, not the corresponding one in the language file, is there a built-in way to get the language file constant, given the value and the language file?

As an example, my language file reads:

```
COM_MY_COMPONENT_FOO="bar"
```

And in my table I have:

```
+-------+-----------------------+
| id    |        some_value     |
+-------+-----------------------+
|   1   |  COM_MY_COMPONENT_FOO |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

Is there any way to get "COM_MY_COMPONENT_FOO" starting from "foo" (given that I already know the language file used by the user)? Reading the whole language file and reversing it might be too costly, even if I create a separated language file specifically for the "some_value" column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's far from perfect or elegant, but I found a working solution and I'll post it here for anybody unlucky enought to need this in the future.

Since language files are simple .ini files it's easy to read them as an associative array in PHP with [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/it/function.parse-ini-file.php) and reversing an associative array can be done with [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php). Adding a simple control with `isset` allows to replicate JText behaviour when the string isn't defined in the language file:

```
$reverselang = array_flip(parse_ini_file($path_to_lang_file));
if(isset($reverselang[$my_string]){
      return $reverselang[$my_string];
}
return $my_string;
```